# How to paint next line from txt file when clicking button java?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui3C implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("change word");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    File plik = new File("C:/hehe.txt");

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        String xde=null;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(plik);
            xde = in.nextLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        g.drawString(xde, 75, 100);
    }
}
```

After i run this i see the first line of the txt file, however when I click on the button I don't see the second line. Can someone explain me what is wrong with my code ? I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that pressing the button knows nothing of the text file or how to read from it... Currently, you press the button and it calls repaint(). repaint doesn't know anything about files or text. Think about what would need to happen when the button is pressed, so that you can get to the next line of text. One way to do this might be to be create a method like getNextLineOfText() that is called when the button is pressed and that method returns just the next line and you append it to what's currently showing (or the method itself appends it). Right now, there is no way to access the scanner to read more lines of text.

Maybe these ideas will help you get to the right solution?